# Wordpress: is_page() if statement is not displaying content

Tags: php, html, wordpress, if-statement

I am trying to alter a shortcode dependent on the page which means I need to determine what page we are on and what shortcode to use.

When I try the below code the sidebar disappears completely leading me to believe that it clearly isn't working. The sidebar appears with the working shortcode when I remove the IF statement from the code however this is needed.

If you have any ideas on whats not working correctly then please feel free to shed some light on it (I have seen some similar questions however non of them have ever received answers).

```
<aside id="drinks-gallery" class="widget widget_gallery">
<div class="gallery-inner">
    <h3 class="widget-title">View The Gallery</h3>
    <p>Don't just take our word for it, take a look at some of our drinks!</p>
    <?php 
    if (is_page('drinks-packages')) {
        echo do_shortcode('[ngg_images source="galleries" container_ids="1" display_type="photocrati-nextgen_basic_thumbnails" override_thumbnail_settings="1" thumbnail_width="110" thumbnail_height="62" thumbnail_crop="1" images_per_page="20" number_of_columns="2" ajax_pagination="0" show_all_in_lightbox="0" use_imagebrowser_effect="0" show_slideshow_link="0" slideshow_link_text="&#91;Show slideshow&#93;" order_by="sortorder" order_direction="ASC" returns="included" maximum_entity_count="500"]')
    };?>
</div>
```

Comment: try to change the `drinks-packages` to the id of the page

Comment: Firstly, If you replace your do_shortcode echo with "Hello" do you see "Hello" on the page - I am checking your conditional ;)

Comment: enable debug mode on Your development environment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first line of your if statement seems incorrect.

Change this:

`if (is_page('drinks-packages'){`

to:

`if (is_page('drinks-packages')) {`

and remove the last `)` as well.

Comment: that should do it

Comment: I have edited the code to be just like yours however this still does not appear. When changing it to the page id it still does not work. Do you need any additional information?

Comment: I tested what you tried and it is definitely possible what you are attempting. You still may have errors, it is best to display them with define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ). From your example you are missing a semi-colon after the closing bracket for example.